# Merge DLL into EXE?

Tags: c#, dll, merge, ilmerge

I have two DLL files which I'd like to include in my EXE file to make it easier to distribute it. I've read a bit here and there how to do this, even found a good thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631567/possible-to-merge-a-dll-into-a-net-exe), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056486/how-to-use-ilmerge-to-merge-dlls-into-an-exe-file), but it's far too complicated for me and I need real basic instructions on how to do this.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010, and please excuse my "low standard" question, but I feel like I'm one or two level below everyone else's expercise :-/ If someone could point out how to merge these DDL files into my EXE in a step-by-step guide, this would be **really** awesome!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

For .NET Framework 4.5

```
ILMerge.exe /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /out:finish.exe insert1.exe insert2.dll
```

[ILMerge](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630)

1. Open CMD and cd to your directory. Let's say: `cd C:\test`
2. Insert the above code.
3. `/out:finish.exe` replace `finish.exe` with any filename you want.
4. Behind the `/out:finish.exe` you have to give the files you want to be
   combined.

Comment: Hurray, that worked. The problem was a "\" at the end of the directory path which was too much.

Comment: I just followed your instructions as you mention above. still not merged. please help me. In Command Prompt : `ILMerge.exe /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /out:finish.exe myExe.exe mfc100u.dll mfc110u.dll msvcp110.dll` Error: `An exception occurred during merging: ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location 'C:\test\my folder\mfc 100u.dll'. Skipping and processing rest of arguments.` Any idea whats gonin wrong ?

Comment: Sometimes you have to 1) use `Program Files (x86)` 2) type the full path to ILMerge. Use `/target:exe` for console applications.

Comment: Windows by-default comes with .NET framework here `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`. So you can also use `/targetplatform:"v2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"` or  `/targetplatform:"v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"`

Answer (score 41):

Use [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura).

You just have to **install the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody) and then do a build**. The final executable will be **standalone**.

Comment: this is a very interesting project. but it seems to be a plugin for [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/).. so you could improve this answer a bit by providing some information on **Mono.Cecil** and **Fody** (as they are both dependencies, and are really the most relevant to the underline premise).  But, yea, the plugin itself does seem to make it 'easier' to embed and distribute dlls in a configurable manner.

Comment: This is voodoo. Unbelievably easy. `Install-Package Costura.Fody` and Bam! your build will produce one big fat exe.

Comment: Doesnt quite work but i support this is can happen in some cases. (Can't build and i have an error)

Comment: Wow - I struggled for 3 days trying to get iLMerge to work with several 3rd party dlls that had multiple other references I had to point to, and even though I had all dependencies added it still did not work and upon examining the logs it was mutating some of the namespace names, saying they were duplicate.  (They were inside the 3rd party assemblies)  This worked just as easy as @CristianDiaconescu said.

Answer (score 25):

Download [ilmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630%20%22IlMerge) and [ilmergre gui](http://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/) . makes joining the files so easy
ive used these and works great

Answer (score 18):

Reference the DLL´s to your Resources and and use the AssemblyResolve-Event to return the Resource-DLL.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {

            Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            //Get the Name of the AssemblyFile
            var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";

            //Load form Embedded Resources - This Function is not called if the Assembly is in the Application Folder
            var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(name));
            if (resources.Count() > 0)
            {
                var resourceName = resources.First();
                using (Stream stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    if (stream == null) return null;
                    var block = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
                    return Assembly.Load(block);
                }
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I don't understand the slightest thing of what you wrote there ;-) Where do I have to put this code into?

Comment: Are you using a WPF or a WindowsForms Application?

Comment: Ok, first you have to add the DLL´s to your project-Resources. Add a folder "Resources" to your Solution and just put your dll´s in there. Right click on your project -> Properties -> Resources. There click "Add Resource" and add your dll´s. After that go to your program.cs file and add the code to your Main() before everything else.

Comment: For WinForms try this code instead of the code above:


            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, arg) =>
            {
                if (arg.Name.StartsWith("Your_DLL")) return Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.Your_DLL);
                return null;
            };

Comment: Okay, I used your shortened version, but my IDE tells me that the name "Assembly" is not available in this context :-/

Comment: Add a using System.Reflection;

Comment: And to ensure that the referenced dll´s are not copied to the output dir, you have to select your dll´s from References and set the property "Copy Local" to false.

Comment: So I included this code snippet for each DLL, but the EXE won't start if the DLLs aren't in the same folder (copied the EXE to desktop to test it). - And I couldn't find this property. How do I get to the *References*? If I go to the program's resources, I can't edit their properties (except for Comment, Filename, FileType, Persistence and Type).

Comment: In your Solution Explorer there is a point "References". The Point, where you added your dll to use it in your program. There are all referenced dll listed. Select your dll and change "Copy Local" to false.

Comment: I did that, even changing WMPLib's and AXVLC's Interop type to "false" to let me change "local copy" to false. I created a pastebin to show you the code snippet in my Program.cs: [pastebin entry](http://pastebin.com/na9GUcsS)

Answer (score 10):

Download

[ILMerge](http://microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630)

Call

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:c:\output.exe c:\input.exe C:\input.dll
```

Comment: Add: `/target:winexe /target
platform:"v4,C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"` to it if you have a .NEt framework 4.5 application :).

Comment: This results in the following error message:
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Core. - I created a bat file with the following content:     `ilmerge /target:winexe my_exe.exe my_dll.dll /out:merged.exe`

Comment: @Momro Try with the target platform parameter ;).

Comment: Ok, so I have this command: `ilmerge /target:winexe /target:platform:"v4,c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\" /out:merged.exe my_exe.exe my_dll.dll`, but the prompt says that I have to specify at least one input fil and an output file. I also exchanged the out parametre with the inputs with no result.

Answer (score 9):

1. [Install ILMerge](http://microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630)
   as the other threads tell you to
2. Then go to the installation folder, by default
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge`
3. Drag your Dll's and Exes to that folder
4. Shift-Rightclick in that folder and choose open command prompt
5. Write

   ```
   ilmerge myExe.exe Dll1.dll /out:merged.exe
   ```

   Note that you should write your exe first.

There you got your merged exe. This might not be the best way if your going to
do this multiple times, but the simplest one for a one time use, I would
recommend putting Ilmerge to your path.

Comment: I just followed your instructions as you mention above.
I have also put `ilmerge` to my system path. 
still not merged. please help me.  
In Command Prompt :
`>ilmerge myExe.exe mfc100u.dll mfc110u.dll /out:final.exe` 


Error: `An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location 'C:\test\my folder\mfc
100u.dll'. Skipping and processing rest of arguments.` 


Any idea whats gonin wrong ?

Comment: Looks like your dlls name contains a space? Try putting quotes around it

Comment: Thanx for reply. But only in this my above comment, `mfc100u.dll` have space. I want to merge more than one `dll` file. I have also try `ILMerge GUI`. But still facing the same problem. Please help me.

Comment: Could not get the above examples from other users to work, but this work perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
    /* PUT THIS LINE IN YOUR CLASS PROGRAM MAIN() */           
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, arg) => { if (arg.Name.StartsWith("YOURDLL")) return Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.YOURDLL); return null; }; 
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

First add the DLL´s to your project-Resources. Add a folder "Resources"

Answer (score 6):

**2019 Update** (just for reference):

Starting with **.NET Core 3.0**, this feature is supported [**out of the box**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables). To take advantage of the single-file executable publishing, just add the following line to the project configuration file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now, `dotnet publish` should produce a single .exe file without using any external tool.

More documentation for this feature is available at https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/design.md.

Comment: Nice, this works but you just need to specify `RuntimeIdentifier` or `RuntimeIdentifiers` and the file gains about 65.4 MB.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [official documentation](https://www.benjaminscabbia.co.uk/files/ILMerge.doc). This is also automatically downloaded at step 2.

Below is a really simple way to do it and I've successfully built my app using `.NET framework 4.6.1`

1. Install ILMerge nuget package either via gui or commandline:

   ```
   Install-Package ilmerge
   ```
2. Verify you have downloaded it. Now Install (not sure the command for this, but just go to your nuget packages): 
   [image]
   Note: You probably only need to install it for one of your solutions if you have multiple
3. Navigate to your solution folder and in the packages folder you should see 'ILMerge' with an executable:

   ```
   \FindMyiPhone-master\FindMyiPhone-master\packages\ILMerge.2.14.1208\tools
   ```

   [image]
4. Now here is the executable which you could copy over to your `\bin\Debug` (or whereever your app is built) and then in commandline/powershell do something like below:

   ```
   ILMerge.exe myExecutable.exe myDll1.dll myDll2.dll myDlln.dll myNEWExecutable.exe
   ```

You will now have a new executable with all your libraries in one!

Comment: For me it is the best way to update ILMerge, thanks @benscabbia

Answer (score 1):

**I Found The Solution Below are the Stpes:-**

1. Download ILMerge.msi and Install it on your Machine.
2. Open Command Prompt
3. type cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge Preess Enter
4. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ILMerge.exe /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
   /out:NewExeName.exe SourceExeName.exe DllName.dll

**For Multiple Dll :-**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>ILMerge.exe /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
/out:NewExeName.exe SourceExeName.exe DllName1.dll DllName2.dll DllName3.dll

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question for `VB.NET`. It shouldn't however be too hard to convert. You embedd the `DLL's` into your `Ressource` folder and on the first usage, the 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event gets fired.

If you want to reference it during development, just add a normal `DLL` reference to your project.

[Embedd a DLL into a project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025506/1028323)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: if you're trying to load a non-ILOnly assembly, then

```
Assembly.Load(block)
```

won't work, and an exception will be thrown:
[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005409/exception-with-resolving-assemblies-attempt-to-load-an-unverifiable-executable)

I overcame this by creating a temporary file, and using

```
Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile)
```

Answer (score -2):

The command should be the following script:

```
ilmerge myExe.exe Dll1.dll /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\" /out:merged.exe /out:merged.exe
```