# wpf dll merge in exe file + compression (.net 4.6.1)

Tags: .net, wpf, merge

I have WPF app with 3 dll's, and I just cracked my brain trying to put this thing in single "exe".

also there is no packer for .net 4.6.1, i used Rugland Packer for (.Net) but it only work with .net 4.0 :( Is there any alternatives for 4.6.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge DLL into EXE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137937/merge-dll-into-exe)