# How to create a single file in a WPF Net5 application?

Tags: c#

If I am not wrong, it seems that I can publish an application in a single file, so I can get only only one exe file  that contains all the needed to work.

First I have tried the publish wizard, and I check the option self contained, produce single file and ready to run. But I get about 300 files.

Then I have tried this command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile=true -c Release -o publish
```

And I get the same result.

Also I have tried this:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile=true -c Release -o publish
```

In this case I don't set the self contained because in somewhere I have read that is not needed when when single file is set, because if you want a single file, it is imply self contained. Anyway, I get always the same result.

My application is a wpf application in which I get an exe and I am using Net 5.

Which is the correct way to get a single .exe file?

Thanks.

PD: the documentation tells, in the publish wizard, I have to check the 3 checks that I check. But I don't get a unique file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge DLL into EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137937/merge-dll-into-exe)

Comment: I have stupid question - did you check publish directory?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the publish directory. In this directory is where I have many files, not only the exe, but also another dlls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the `Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets`, it seems that the property got renamed to `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` and after I set this to `True` in a simple project, I indeed get a single file.

Other properties in this group, which may interest you are `IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile` and `IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract`.

EDIT: [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12363)