# How do you package a NuGet (and its dependencies) into the executable so that there is only one resulting file?

Tags: c#, dll

I made an application which exports an Excel worksheet. My friend told me that he wants to use it. The problem is, it uses EPPlus which has a LOT of dependencies. How do I send him the application without including all of the nasty DLLs (totaling over 180 MB)?

P.S. Costura.Fody does **not** work. It only packaged EPPlus.dll, but it didn't include its dependencies. I have also tried the `dotnet publish` with `PublishSingleFile` and `IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile` set to true, but it still outputted some leftover DLLs.

Also, I am using .NET 5.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137937/merge-dll-into-exe @bg117

Comment: Apart from adding `PublishSingleFile` in your `dotnet publish` command, you also need to set the Deployment mode to "Self-contained" by adding `--self-contained true`.

Comment: @Yash Gupta, unfortunately, I have already tried that, but same result.

Comment: @Djordje Nedovic, I will look into it later. Thanks.

Comment: @DjordjeNedovic, unfortunately it also does not work. When I run it, it doesn't open anything.