# How to merge a subset of linked dll files with one exe file (C#, WinForms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, ilmerge

I have a solution with two C# projects: One WinForms application (exe) and one library (dll). Multiple external dll files are referenced. I would like to merge the output of my projects into one exe file, while keeping the other dll files separately, i.e. instead of

- myApp.exe
- myLib.dll
- externalLib1.dll
- externalLib2.dll
- ...

I would like to have

- myMergedAppAndLib.exe
- externalLib1.dll
- externalLib2.dll
- ...

Is this actually possible?
I am aware of the ILMerge tool, but it seems to be deprecated and I don't know whether it is ok not to include all referenced dll files.
I am also aware of the publishing option in Visual Studio *Produce single file*, but to my understanding this will also merge the external dll files, right?

I cannot merge the two projects, because the library project is also used for a third project (another WinForms exe).

Related SO question: [merge-dll-into-exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137937/merge-dll-into-exe)

Comment: ILMerge was never something i would call official it might be no longer maintained but should atleast work for all pre core frameworks. Changing myLib into a [Shared project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) might be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Ralf! I think the Shared Project approach is the way to go! I was not aware of this kind of project.

Comment: Apparently, Shared Projects do not support the WinForms designer, i.e. I cannot use it. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/306210/winforms-in-shared-projects-designer-doesnt-work