# How to include two projects in one publishing profile

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two projects. I want project A to contain all of the published files from Project B.

I added Project B as a reference to Project A. This gives me the exe file for Project B in Project A's output. However, all DLLs from Project B are missing within Project A, which results in the included exe file not working.

Is there any easy way to reference Project B in Project A with all of it's dependencies so when I publish project A, it contains the latest version of Project B fully runnable?

Comment: Yes it is possible, are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: yes. Using latest Version of VS Community

Comment: Okay, your project B cannot give as output an exe file, I mean if you intention is to get access to the DLL's generated by Project B on A, Project B should be a Class Library Project, on this way you will get as output DLL's and this will appear on the Build of Project A when it gets built or published.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks. Putting everything into a Class Library and referencing it in Porject B fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't quite understand why you want to refer to B's exe. But if you really need to merge dll to EXE, you can try ILMerge. For details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137937/merge-dll-into-exe).

Of course, I recommend that you try to put B into the class library and convert it into a dll file, which is referenced in project A. Such information is easy to find, so that all problems will be solved.

Comment: I'm doing this because Project B is a seperate executable file which I want to run independetly from Project A. But I want to ship Project B with the published version of Project A

Comment: @MarvinKlein If this is the condition, ILMerge is a very useful tool for you. It can incorporate DLL into exe. You can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138100/20376806. If you think it is not detailed enough, other information about ILMerge on the Internet is also easy to obtain.